# $.getJSON not returning any data

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to test $.getJSON() on localhost, but no data is returned.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

**PHP:**

```
$person['name'] = !empty($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'name';
$person['age'] = !empty($_GET['age']) ? $_GET['age'] : '00';

return json_encode($person);
?>
```

**HTML / jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.start').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('http://localhost/ewoe/server.php?name=natasha&age=22', alert(data.name));
        })
    }); //end ready
</script>
```

All files can be found in the same directory. 
Although, the error I get after hitting the .start button is `'data not set'`.

Comment: have you checked your browser console to see if your `$.getJSON()` is called, and what the status of the call is?

Comment: this is the error I got in the browser console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost/ewoe/server.php?name=natasha&age=22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually in the PHP output.
The reason is that PHP, being a server-side language does not output to the HTML the stuff with `return`. If you want to **print them out** you have to `echo` them.

Therefore `return` is not the answer, the answer is `echo`.

Your php should be:

```
<?php

$person['name'] = !empty($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'name';
$person['age'] = !empty($_GET['age']) ? $_GET['age'] : '00';

echo json_encode($person);
```

If you are getting errors on the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` you should try giving a local path, not the full path:

```
$.getJSON('server.php?name=natasha&age=22', ...);
```

-
**NOTE**

Don't really know what you are doing there, but as a note, be carefull to possible manipulation of your script.

By doing this, someone can see the source of your file and send request to the `server.php` by going to `www.yoursite/ewoe/server.php?name=....`

Perhaps you should use the `$_POST` in the PHP and jQuery `$.post` requesting json format, like this:

```
$.post('server.php', {name : 'natasha', age: 22}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.name)
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Sure, my pleasure. ;D

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap alert into anonymous function:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/ewoe/server.php?name=natasha&age=22', function(data) {
    alert(data.name);
});
```

Comment: When you go to `http://localhost/ewoe/server.php?name=natasha&age=22` in new tab, what do you see?

Comment: Nothing show there because used `return` however when I use `echo` or `print`, I get it on the php page.

Comment: Oh, right, you need to echo or die string content, of course. Also adding Content-type header is a good idea, but optional.

Comment: this is the error I got in the browser console:  

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/ewoe/server.php?name=natasha&age=22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You need to make sure you issue request from the same origin. It means the same protocol, port and domain. You will not be able for example to use `file:///` protocol and make requests to `http://localhost`.

Comment: the request issuer is from the same origin and of the same protocol.
**requester** `http://localhost/ewoe/index.html`
**request receiver** `http://localhost/ewoe/server.php`